# Using curl in bash and ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, curl

I have the following which works in bash:

```
curl -d "{ \"auth_token\": \"secret\", \"current\":"${COUNT}"}" http://lab:3030/widgets/connections
```

But if I tried this in Ruby is fails:

```
`curl -d "{\"auth_token\":\"secret\",\"current\":"#{count}"}" http://lab:3030/widgets/connections`
```

And get this error message:

```
JSON::ParserError - 746: unexpected token at '{auth_token:secret,current:4}':
```

The output of from Ruby appears to look correct on screen but trigger the JSON parser error. What else can I check for?

I was thinking about using a gem like curb-fu but could not figure out how to construct it to look the same as the bash one above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `stdlib`'s [`json`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) to convert the hash:

```
require 'json'

{foo: "bar"}.to_json
#=> "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
```

and [`shellwords`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html) to build the command:

```
require 'shellwords'

['curl', '-d', '{"foo":"bar"}', 'http://example.com/'].shelljoin
#=> "curl -d \\{\\\"foo\\\":\\\"bar\\\"\\} http://example.com/"
```

Complete example:

```
require 'json'
require 'shellwords'

data = {auth_token: secret, current: count}
`#{['curl', '-d', data.to_json, 'http://lab:3030/widgets/connections'].shelljoin}`
```

Comment: I think it's better to include the `require 'shellwords'` in sample code.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have an escaping issue: The quotes are not being escaped properly in the Ruby version. Try this:

```
`curl -d "{\\"auth_token\\":\\"secret\\",\\"current\\":"#{count}"}" http://lab:3030/widgets/connections`
```

This is because both Ruby and the shell escape with the backslash, so escaping happens twice. By adding the extra backslash, the Ruby version is escaped to `\"` instead of just `"` and then shell can escape the quote for you.